# Substr shows last char as?

Tags: php

my problem is kinda simple.
For my website I wrote a **function** to get the first chars of an text to show these in the preview. This works until the last char is an "Umlaut" like ü ä ö.

Is this because it counts these chars double (2 bytes)?

Here is an example:

```
function getFirstChars($str, $count){
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = substr($str, 0, $count);
    return $str;
}

$str = 'Nach Schaffenspausen, Wiedervereinigungen und leider auch einem Schicksalsschlag, kam die 1995 gegründete Band';

echo getFirstChars($str, 100);
```

When i do this i get a ? at the end.

So I tried to change my function and now it works but i have no idea if this is a good solution or not:

```
function getFirstChars($str, $count){
    $str = trim($str);
    $lastChar = substr($str, 0, $count);

    if(mb_detect_encoding($lastChar[$count-1]) == 'UTF-8'){
        $str = substr($str, 0, $count+1);
    }else{
        $str = substr($str, 0, $count);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

The `substr` function is not safe to use for strings that contains multibyte characters. That's because standard string functions like substr doesn't work with characters but with bytes. The two-byte character is treated like two individual characters.

To work with multibyte characters you have to use functions from `mbstring` library. In your case it's `mb_substr`.

You can find more info in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

Answer (score 2):

your `getFirstChars` function will only work if the `mbstring` extension is enabled and `mb_substr` is used. 
For multibyte safe substring, we can use [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) function

```
function getFirstChars($str, $count){
    if(!function_exists('mb_substr')){
      die('enable mbstring extension'); // you may throw an exception too. 
    }
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = mb_substr($str, 0, $count);

    return $str;
}
```